# How to identify type of flash[] messages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I would like to have different style for different type of flash messages: error, notice, success. 
How would I identify the type of flash messages passed to my view?

In my controller, I have:

```
flash[:error] = "Access denied."
```

In my application.html.haml, I have:

```
  - if not flash.empty?
    - flash.each do |key, value|
      %div{:class => "alert-message #{key}"}= value
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you already are, with CSS classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flash` is essentially based on a hash. Each kind of flash message is just the value associated with a symbol key for that type. So `flash[:error]` is for error messages, `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:success]` for their key types. You can even define your own types (just using any symbol). And you can have any number of keys set at once (so you can for example set a `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:error]` in the same request).

In your example, this is creating a `div` with the class `alert-message #{key}`. So, for example, if you set a `flash[:notice]` the output would be:

```
<div class="alert-message notice">Notice message</div>
```

And it will print one for each type you set. So if the request set `flash[:error] = 'something went terribly wrong'` and `flash[:notice] = 'take a look around'`, you'd get this html from that template:

```
<div class="alert-message error">something went terribly wrong</div>
<div class="alert-message notice">take a look around</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. That's exactly the answer I am looking for.